# VSCode React JSX syntax highlighting broken

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Why does the code becomes mostly yellow starting with function App()? This happens in a lot of JSX files. Highlight mode is set to "JavaScript React".

[image]

Comment: whicj formatter extension do you use?

Comment: I use Prettier.

Comment: You can try using this extension `ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets` . It highlights syntax for me that works well

Comment: @SiddhantVarma what it has to do with highlighting? That's snippets you're talking about. As you can see in my example I don't get components in JSX highlighted starting with function App().

Comment: @Neone sorry my bad, the extension I use `Sublime Babel` . You can try it out and see if it works